# Change made to custom config file did not persist in WPF application (windows server 2008 R2)

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have installed a WPF application which contains Custom configuration XML files in App_Data folder.

After installing I have changed one of the XML file and saved it. When new user opens the application for the first time, application is reverting the changes to install time. Not sure whats going on here and what to debug.

I would really appreciate your inputs on this.

**EDIT:**

I found that MSI is running Auto Repair thinking the file is corrupted. Is there any way to avoid auto repair when a particular file is changed.

Comment: Where is your `App_Data` folder located?

Comment: Inside application root folder. I found that MSI is getting installed for every new user and overwriting the modified files, how can I stop this?

Comment: If the application root folder is within the "Program Files" directory, your users won't have access to write to the files. It sounds like you're installing it per-user, which is the only way you can write to the application folder. If that's the case, there's no way to share the XML files between the users.

Comment: I am not writing anything to this file from program. After installing the MSI, I am updating the URL in one of the files manually. When a new user opens the application MSI re installs itself and changes were lost